# Ordering Combinations for Maximum Effectiveness

Tags: php, computer-science, combinations

So recently I was given a problem, which I have been mulling over and am still unable to solve; I was wondering if anyone here could point me in the right direction by providing me with the psuedo code (or at least a rough outline of the pseudo code) for this problem. PS I'll be building in PHP if that makes a difference...

### Specs

There are ~50 people (for this example I'll just call them a,b,c... ) and the user is going to group them into groups of three (people in the groups may overlap), and in the end there will be 50-100 groups (ie {a,b,c}; {d,e,f}; {a,d,f}; {b,c,l}...). *

*So far it is easy, it is a matter of building an html form and processing it into a multidimensional array*

---

There are ~15 time slots during the day (eg 9:00AM, 9:20AM, 9:40AM...). Each of these groups needs to meet once during the day. And during one time slot the person cannot be double booked (ie 'a' cannot be in 2 different groups at 9:40AM).

*It gets tricky here, but not impossible, my best guess at how to do this would be to brute force it (pick out sets of groups that have no overlap (eg {a,b,c}; {l,f,g}; {q,n,d}...) and then just put each into a time slot*

---

Finally, the schedule which I output needs to be 'optimized', by that I mean that 'a' should have minimal time between meetings (so if his first meeting is at 9:20AM, his second meeting **shouldn't** be at 2:00PM).

*Here's where I am lost, my only guess would be to build many, many schedules and then rank them based on the average waiting time a person has from one meeting to the next*

---

However My 'solutions' (I hesitate to call them that) require too much brute force and would take too long to create. Are there simpler, more elegant solutions?

Comment: @Tomas: I'm a little confused. 50 people will need to be split up in 50-100 groups, where a single person needs to be in multiple groups? Why is the range of group numbers so large and, secondly, do all members need to be part of the same amount of groups or can one be part of two groups, and another guy of six? I think it's possible to do this more elegantly, by taking a smarter approach (brute force is by definition a dumb approach), but I'm missing too many variables to solve this, I feel. Or maybe I'm just not smart enough...:lol:

Comment: @Battle_707, When I was posting this I was thinking that exact same thing :D . So first of all the group number is defined by the user and can actually be any real integer (I was estimating 50-100), but that shouldn't matter because if your code only supports 100 groups and the user only enters 53 you can just make empty groups... and to address your second question: no, there is no standard for the number of groups each person can be on. However that just gave me an idea! Wouldn't knowing the maximum number of groups one person is on help us in some way?

Comment: Well, yes and no. I would much rather have it if you told me every user could be 'used' the same amount of times, I think (this is just a gut feeling, I haven't done any of the calculations yet). And it's annoying that the amount of groups are so dynamic. I suppose it has to be +/-1, taking that all groups need to contain 3 people, and with 53 subscribers, you can't create all full groups using every member just once. Another question, though: is there a limit to the amount of groups that can have an appointment at one given time, or can all people/ groups meet at the same time?

Comment: @Battle_707, no limit, so if no person overlaps this should only take 1 time slot. With that in mind, it brings me back to my original idea (I'll call all the groups g1, g2, g3, etc): put g1 in timeslot 1, then test if g1 has overlap w/ g2, if yes continue to next step, if no then put g2 in timeslot one. Then check if g3 has overlap w/ groups currently in timeslot 1, etc. Once you have checked all groups, remove all groups in timeslot 1 from array and repeat process with remaining groups and timeslot 2.

Comment: Let me get this right... With your numbers (of 50 ppl)... There is a total of 19600 possible groups (50 C 3). And assuming ideal allocation (highly possible with large groups), You have a total of about ~6534 sessions. That's alot of group meetings to meet them all O.o lol...

Im guessing you either need this for an event / tournament / etc

Comment: Anyway, if the number of sessions is small (~100?), It is possible to generate a more elegant solution to the problem, with randomization. So if you do not need a perfect ideal solution for all ~6000+ sessions. There can be easily done with PHP + SQL.

Comment: OK, I didn't think you guys would want the full story, but here it is: A person I know works at a university where once a year they have to have thesis review panels (I think that was the name). Anyway these panels consist of 3 professors and some professors appear on a lot of panels and some professors appear on only one or two. The university likes to hammer all these meetings out at once so they try to schedule them in one day. These professors either come from inside the university or neighboring universities...

Comment: @Tomas : Additionally, i need to know if it is ok, for a pair of user to stay together for the first 100+ sessions or so. It would simplify the code, but awkward in real life.

Comment: Actually....if there is no regulation regarding how many times a person is supposed to appear and how often he/ she is part of a group, why not just draw per time slot? Just pick as many people as you have seats for each slot and then track how long ago it has been since a person has been picked. This is VERY easy to code as it is very straightforward. The only issue with this is that there is no control over the amount of groups formed...

Comment: Hmm... if that is the case... isn't it possible to just keep randomizing the combinations (Not actually working them out). And ensure that members have the same amount of meetings, by the end of X session (where X is the amount of papers).

Comment: [con't] but either way it would be preferable if they didn't have to wait hours in between their meetings. Currently the university has a professor sit down and create the schedule by hand, and it takes 2-3 hrs of guess work (LOL, sucks for that guy). With that in mind I thought that computer science must have some elegant solution to this. If you know one @pico.creator pls share the pseudo code as an answer.

Comment: @pico.creator there will definetly not be more than 100 papers, so there shouldn't be '100+ sessions'. Also what do you mean randomizing the calculations without working them out?

Comment: @Tomas: I see you commented while I was commenting, so as a feedback to the real-live situation, I would like to vote my idea of looking at it at a per-session situation, rather than a per-group situation (if I may be that arrogant x) ). This will very easily allow for the professors to be only available during specific times of the day as well (which I assume is something that will happen). I can mock up some psuedo code for you if you would like that.

Comment: sure show me some psuedo code, maybe we can build on it.

Comment: I did a similar one for a games event at school, using EXCEL. And lots of queries. If you do not mind the randomness though. Basically, it just randomizes the groupings, and checks if it has been done before, else it just repeats itself : I gonna dig it up for pesudo code

This was the important reason why i ask if you need an ideal solution?, cause if the sessions are alot lesser then the total possible, randomization would save alot in processing power. But will crash the computer near the last few sessions. 

And yup, it is possible to do this in EXCEL with a good computer.

Comment: @Tomas : the random part will be easier explained in my answer... brb haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the table laid out, modified for your scenerio

```
+----User_Details------+  //You may or may not need this
| UID | Particulars... |
+----------------------+

+----User_Timeslots---------+  //Time slots per collumn
| UID | SlotNumber(bool)... |  //true/false if the user is avaliable
+---------------------------+  //SlotNumber is replaced by s1, s2, etc

+----User_Arrangements--------+  //Time slots per collumn
| UID | SlotNumber(string)... |  //Group session string
+-----------------------------+
```

Note: That the string in the Arrangement table, was in the following format : JSON

> '[12,15,32]' //From SMALLEST to BIGGEST!

So what happens in the arrangement table, was that a script [Or an EXCEL column formula] would go through each slot per session, and randomly create a possible session. Checking all previous sessions for conflicts.

```
/**
* Randomise a session, in which data is not yet set
**/
function randomizeSession( sesionID ) {
    for( var id = [lowest UID], id < [highest UID], id++ ) {
        if( id exists ) {
            randomizeSingleSession( id, sessionID );
        } //else skips
    }
}

/**
* Randomizes a single user in a session, without conflicts in previous sessions
**/
function randomizeSingleSession( id, sessionID ) {

    convert sessionID to its collumns name =)
    get the collumns name of all ther previous session

    if( there is data, false, or JSON ) {
        Does nothing (Already has data)
    }

    if( ID is avaliable in time slot table (for this session) ) {
        Get all IDs who are avaliable, and contains no data this session
        Get all the UID previous session
        while( first time || not yet resolved ) {
            Randomly chose 2
            if( there was conflict in UID previous session ) {
                try again (while) : not yet resolved
            } else {
                resolved
            }
        }

        Registers all 3 users as a group in the session

    } else {
        Set session result to false (no attendance)
    }
}
```

You will realize the main part of the assignment of groups is via randomization. However, as the amount of sessions increases. There will be more and more data to check against for conflicts. Resulting to a much slower performance. However large being, ridiculously large, to an almost perfect permutation/combination formulation.

**EDIT:**

This setup will also help ensure, that as long as the user is available, they will be in a group. Though you may have pockets of users, having no user group (a small number). These are usually remedied by recalculating (for small session numbers). Or just manually group them together, even if it is a repeat. (having a few here and there does not hurt). Or alternatively in your case, along with the remainders, join several groups of 3's to form groups of 4. =)

And if this can work for EXCEL with about 100+ ppl, and about 10 sessions. I do not see how this would not work in SQL + PHP. Just that the calculations may actually take some considerable time both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for those who just join in on this post, please read through all the comments to the question before considering the contents of this answer, as this will very likely fly over your head.

Here is some pseudo code in PHP'ish style:

```
/* Array with profs (this is one dimensional here for the show, but I assume
it will be multi-dimensional, filled with availability and what not;
For the sake of this example, let me say that the multi-dimensional array
contains the following keys: [id]{[avail_from],[avail_to],[last_ses],[name]}*/
$profs = array_fill(0, $prof_num, "assoc_ids");

// Array with time slots, let's say UNIX stamps of begin time
$times = array_fill(0, $slot_num, "time");

// First, we need to loop through all the time slots
foreach ($times as $slot) {

    // See when session ends
    $slot_end = $slot + $session_time;

    // Now, run through the profs to see who's available
    $avail_profs = array(); // Empty
    foreach ($profs as $prof_id => $data) {

        if (($data['avail_from'] >= $slot) && ($data['avail_to'] >= $slot_end)) {

            $avail_prof[$prof_id] = $data['last_ses'];

        }

    }

    /* Reverse sort the array so that the highest numbers (profs who have been
    waiting the longest) will be up top */
    arsort($avail_profs);
    $profs_session = array_slice($avail_profs, 0, 3);
    $profs_session_names = array(); // Empty

    // Reset the last_ses counters on those profs
    foreach ($profs_session as $prof_id => $last_ses) {


        $profs[$prof_id]['last_ses'] = 0;
        $profs_session_names[0] = $profs[$prof_id]['name'];

    }

    // Now, loop through all profs to add one to their waiting time
    foreach ($profs as $prof_id = > $data) {

       $profs[$prof_id]['last_ses']++;

    }

    print(sprintf('The %s session will be held by: %s, $s, and %s<br />', $slot,
                   $profs_session_names[0], $profs_session_names[1],
                   $profs_session_names[2]);

    unset ($profs_session, $profs_session_names, $avail_prof);

}
```

That should print something like:

```
The 9:40am session will be held by: C. Hicks, A. Hole, and B.E.N. Dover
```

Comment: Actually, now I think about it....this will do the _opposite_ of optimizing. It will do make sure that the people who have waited the longest will go first, meaning that it will take about 17 sessions before the first three people are picked again. Also, there is little random about this (it is, until it's second run). The randomness would work slightly better when multiple sessions would be held at the same time, but still, there is little optimization about this....

Comment: 5 minute barrier past, so here's a comment to my previous comment: Since I have established that there will be a fixed time of some sorts between the reappearing of a professor (namely: (num_profs / 3) / ses_per_slot), we can then 'regroup' those sessions closer to each other. In other words, now we know the space between people coming back, we can move them closer to previous appearance, without knowing exactly where a person is...

Answer (score 0):

I see an object model consisting of:

- Panelists: a fixed repository of of your the panelists (Tom, Dick, Harry, etc)
- Panel: consists of X Panelists (X=3 in your case)
- Timeslots: a fixed repository of your time slots. Assuming fixed duration and only occurring on a single day, then all you need is track is start time.
- Meeting: consists of a Panel and Timeslot
- Schedule: consists of many Meetings

Now, as you have observed, the optimization is the key. To me the question is: "Optimized with respect to what criteria?". Optimal for Tom might means that the Panels on which he is a member lay out without big gaps. But Harry's Panels may be all over the board. So, perhaps for a given Schedule, we compute  something like `totalMemberDeadTime` (= sum of all dead time member gaps in the Schedule). An optimal Schedule is the one that is minimal with respect to this sum

If we are interested in computing a technically optimal schedule among the universe of all schedules, I don't really see an alternative to brute force .

Perhaps that universe of Schedules does not need to be as big as might first appear. It sounds like the panels are constituted first and then the issue is to assign them to Meetings which them constitute a schedule. So, we removed the variability in the panel composition; the full scope of variability is in the Meetings and the Schedule. Still, sure seems like a lot of variability there.

But perhaps optimal with respect to *all* possible Schedules is more than we really need.

Might we define a Schedule as acceptable if no panelist has total dead time more than X? Or failing that, if no more than X panelists have dead time more than X (can't satisfy everyone, but keep the screwing down to a minimum)? Then the user could assign meeting for panels containing the the more "important" panelists first, and less-important guys simply have to take what they get. Then all we have to do is fine a single acceptable Schedule

Might it be sufficient for your purposes to compare any two Schedules? Combined with an interface (I'm seeing a drag-and-drop interface, but that's clearly beyond the point) that allows the user to constitute a schedule, clone it into a second schedule, and tweak the second one, looking to reduce aggregate dead time until we can find one that is acceptable.

Anyway, not a complete answer. Just thinking out loud. Hope it helps.